# Launching activity of another project which is not a library | Java / Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am using some libraries and one project (GrazeRSS - https://github.com/travistabbal/GrazeRSS) in my project

I have added GrazeRSS to my project "Java Build Path" in the "Projects" tab..

I am having problem launching one of it's activities from my project..

First - I added the other project activity to my project manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.grazerss.feedly.FeedlyLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" />
```

Second - I tried to start the activity from my project using:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.grazerss.feedly.newton", "com.grazerss.feedly.FeedlyLoginActivity"));
            startActivity(i);
```

I also tried:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ServiceProviderActivity.this,
                    com.grazerss.feedly.FeedlyLoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

ServiceProviderActivity is one of my project classes

When running the application I get:

```
03-13 02:41:36.644: E/dalvikvm(26634): Could not find class 'com.grazerss.feedly.FeedlyLoginActivity', referenced from method com.xd.triple.activities.ServiceProviderActivity$1.onClick
```

And when clicking on the button that initiates the "FeedlyLoginActivity" i get:

```
03-13 02:41:25.554: E/AndroidRuntime(25984): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.grazerss.feedly.FeedlyLoginActivity
```

Does anyone have idea whats going on here?

I have tried for 4 hours fixing this problem already..

Thanks in advanced,

Din.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Second - I tried to start the activity from my project using:

That's not correct, unless *your* app's package name in the `<manifest>` is `com.grazerss.feedly.newton`.

> I also tried

That should be better, insofar as it will use your app's own package name.

> Does anyone have idea whats going on here?

There is no such class in your project. Most likely, that is because of:

> I have added GrazeRSS to my project "Java Build Path" in the "Projects" tab..

...which is wrong. Undo that.

Assuming that you are trying to incorporate what's in the `app/` directory of that repository, that's an application. There is no standard means of incorporating one application *in toto* into another, other than by copying all of its files in `res/`, `src/`, and `libs/` into your project's `res/`, `src/`, and `libs/` directories. Or, you could attempt to convert that project into [an Android library project](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) and use it that way.